# match list of emails to another list of eamils in excel

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, match, formula

does anyone have a good solution for searching in excel a list of emails towards another lsit of emails? Challenge is in following:

List one has emails this way, `A2-A4`:

```
bob@yahoo.com
ken@hotmail.com
barbra@gmail.com
```

I need to match these emails towards another list, where emails are in following format, cells `T2-T6`:

```
Bob Smith <bob@yahoo.com>
Bob S <boby@gmail.com>
Hotmail<ken@hotmail.com>
"ken.patrik.idontknow"<ken.patrik.idontknow@gmail.com>
barbra<barbra@gmail.com>
```

I tried this formula `=Match(A2;T:T;0)` but I not sure whether this might be the only and best way. Thankful in advance for kind advices.

Comment: You are currently looking for exact matches. Though `MATCH` does accept wildcards , so try to include that. *Sidenote*: Don't forget to revisit older questions and see if you can close them by accepting an answer. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you are unsure how to do so.

Comment: Is it enough for you, if you know that an entry of list one is in list two or do you need to count all matches?

Answer (score 0):

You can throw in some wildcard, and you need to concatenate your lookupvalue with `<` and `>` to prevent unwanted matches, e.g: `bob@yahoo.com` within `Spongebob@yahoo.com`.

```
=MATCH("*<"&A2&">",T:T,0)
```